# Run prettier from nodejs using child_process.execSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am trying to run prettier from within a nodejs application. The code is as follows:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
console.log(execSync('prettier --help').toString());
```

When I run my application, the output is as follows:

```
child_process.js:669
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: prettier --help
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/borre/cubonacci/services/ui/temp.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

I have found no useful way to extract more information as to why the command fails. There is no output in either `stdout` or `stderr`.

I am able to run other applications in exactly the same way. For example, replacing `prettier` with `code` will start VS code without issues.

How do I properly run Prettier from nodejs?

Comment: Did you install `prettier` globally?

Comment: try running `which prettier` and see what output it gives. looks prettier is not installed

Comment: @EricGoncalves Yes prettier is installed globally. @AshishModi `which prettier` yields exactly what it is supposed to: `/usr/local/bin/prettier`.